# How to configure Jenkins for proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, jenkins

Apparently there is no way to configure proxy in Jenkins. The proxy settings that are available through "Manage Jenkins --> Manage Plugins --> Advanced" are only for plugins. So if I try to configure it there, I still don't see this configuration on System Properties page.

The only way that I managed to configure the proxy successfully is via command line, for example:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> -DJENKINS_HOME="C:\.jenkins" -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=<port>
```

But I have Jenkins set up as Windows service and not sure how can I supply these command line parameters. When I look at the task managed, Jenkins process appears with a bunch of parameters but I am not sure where does it read it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the parameters Jenkins starts with are configured in: `jenkins.xml` file in Jenkins home directory in the `<arguments></arguments>` variable.

It is possible to just add the java parameters into this field. To verify that the parameters had been accepted, go to Manage Jenkins --> System Information and view the list of System Properties used by Jenkins. For example, the parameters that I needed:

[image]